# Why isn't this CSS :after triangle appearing correctly?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a CSS :after triangle the usual way. But it does not look as a triangle at all, please see http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/eX3HL/:

```
/* triangle after */
#st:after {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    content:"";
    border-top:4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
    border-left:4px solid black;
}

#st {
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

If I change "position:relative" to "position:absolute" the triangle will become a triangle. But that does not work where I want it (because it is on a float div).

What can I do?

Comment: Thanks for the indentation edit, @BoltClock. Could I have jsfiddle do that for me in some way?

Comment: That was not my edit, that was @Adrift's. I just removed some tags that did not need to be there.

Comment: Thanks, I should be more careful. It looks like the width and height also can be removed. (I will do that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to fix the triangle

```
#st:after {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    content:"";
    border-top:4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
    border-left:4px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eX3HL/2/

Comment: Oh, a really suprising solution! It works, but how did you find out that?

Comment: @Leo Inline elements do not have height or width, so in order for the height and width to take it needed to be inline-block, block wouldn't work because it would be on a new line.

Comment: You could also make it a normal block and float it left. Inline-block is the same a block is but just tells the rendering engine to take the actual width of an element rather than the whole vertical space (width). PS. Keep in mind that <=IE8 has problems with inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

It's a phenomenon that has to do with the native display of an object. The native `display` property of `span` is `inline`. Inline elements behave like plain text, while block elements behave more like images.

In your example when you do not override the default property of the span your element behaves like text and thus has also an `font-size` shadow-property which is set to `inherit`. It's an unexpected behavior since the shadow-properties are not visible to developers directly, so causing a lot of unclarities. You don't have to just believe my words, here is a proof: http://jsfiddle.net/eX3HL/5/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I had no idea about that. The solution from @Kevin above seems easier since I guess there are no such inherited sizes for inline-block. Or, maybe there are? (But what is a "shadow-property"?)

Comment: Well when you create a div you don't have to specify that that is a block element, the rendering engine of your browser has a set of built-in, default properties that when not overridden by you manually are affecting your DOM. The problem is that those are not directly visible to developers what causes a lot of confusion, I call them shadow-properties because they sit in the "inside of your browser", and are kinda hidden from everyone. @Kevin 's solution to this problem is good, as long as the <=IE8 support doesn't matter you can use both solutions.

Comment: I see, thanks. And I do not plan to support more than standards (and emerging standards that I need). I have to minimize the work so I can focus on what is important.

Comment: Here is minimized example to clarify thighs up. http://jsfiddle.net/eX3HL/7/ The `position: relative;` there is not needed cause I doubt you'll position elements directly relative to the triangle. And keep in mind that setting position to absolute always results in an `block element`.

Comment: Yes, I can do without
    `position: relative;`
but then I can't move the arrow. Good point however about that it creates block!